# Working with a JSON array of objects in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, database-design

I have an SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE pu_events(
  int eid AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  varchar(20) title,
  varchar(255) description, 
  int(11) start_date UNSIGNED,
  int(11) end_date UNSIGNED,
  timestamp created DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  json members
)
```

I plan on populating the members field with a members json object which will be an array of objects containing the user id (uid) and status of attending members, such as:

```
{members: [{uid:1, status:0}, {uid:2, status:1}]}
```

But I'm having trouble finding any resources which describe how to correctly reference this object structure to manipulate it, for example if i wish to 'register' a user to the event, to append their object to the array of members like: (members.push({uid:3, status:0}), or to update the status of a given user once they are confirmed or resign from the event, like: (update members set status = 2 where uid = 1;).

I understand that the pseudo-c I've used is a combination of js & mysql, and i also understand that MySQL now has JSON functions for manipulating this datatype, but I'm confused with the best way to approach this particular use case.

Many thanks for any advice in advance!

Comment: I feel i should clarify; I know i could make this work by pulling the entire contents of the json field into an object, manipulting the object on the server side then re-writing the object back to the database, however I know there are now MySQL functions which are supposed to make that approach redundant.  I'm looking for an explanation of the mysql functions pertaining to manipulation of a json object with this specific structure.

Comment: I don't have experience with this, but https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-json/ seems to have instructions for extracting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper solution is to create another table:

```
CREATE TABLE pu_event_members (
 event_id INT NOT NULL,
 user_id INT NOT NULL,
 status TINYINT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (event_id, user_id)
);
```

Then it's easy to register a new member of the event:

```
INSERT INTO pu_event_members SET event_id=?, user_id=?, status=?
```

Or update their status:

```
UPDATE pu_event_members SET status=? WHERE event_id=? AND user_id=?
```

Comment: So, your solution is don't use the JSON datatype?

Comment: Correct. There's no benefit to using JSON in your case, since each object in your array has the same fields. For the task you described (inserting and updating individual members), it's easier to create a dependent table. One row per member, and columns for each field as I showed. It'll take less space, too.

Comment: But I would have thought iterating through the entire pu_event_members table for update operations will be less efficient as the table grows to 1000+ records?

Comment: If I ask you to look in the telephone book for "Sarah Smith," do you read the whole book?

Comment: So just to clarify, in terms of efficiency/query speed - there will be no negative impact to using this extra table to store event metadata as opposed to the json approach?  It just seems to me that going from a single query to gather event data now needs to be two separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

Working example but only select:

```
select pu_events.*
from pu_events, JSON_TABLE(members, "$.members[*].uid" COLUMNS(f INT PATH '$')) as list
where list.f = 1
```

Mysql 8 has support JSON_TABLE

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html